# How do I search through an ItemCollection of a Pivot control

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm passing the string of a header I want the pivot control on my page to move to like this

```
switch (SelectedItemHeaderString){
    case "News":
        MainPivot.SelectedItem = MainPivot.Items.Where(i => i.Header == "News");
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

How do I find the PivotItem by Header because the following doesn't work.

```
MainPivot.Items.Where(i => i.Header == "News");
```

Comment: Try `MainPivot.Items.Where(i => i.Header.ToString().Equals("News");`

Comment: `i` does not have `.Header` which is the problem, as it's not casting as a `PivotItem`

Comment: Just a guess you could try this: (i => ((PivotItem)i).Header == "News")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MainPivot.Items.Where(i => ((PivotItem)i).Header.ToString() == "News").FirstOrDefault();
```

Hope this will help my comment wasn't working correctly. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Pivots.SelectedItem = Pivots.Items.Cast<PivotItem>().Where(item => "News" == item.Header.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();
```

Some comments:

1. `Items` contains objects and we need to cast to `PivotItem`.
2. Method Where(...) returns IEnumerable and we need only one (method FirstOrDefault)
3. Cast items.Header to string because default equal operator (==) compare object references

Comment: Item needed a cast, BigL's comment worked straight away. I voted you up tho.

Comment: @JosephLeBrech, oh.. I didn't read your comments under the question and provide you working solution. And using .ToString() method is also important part of solution.

Comment: Yes @Ivan.Benko you are right the ToString() and the FirstOrDefault() plays a huge role in the solution, i UpVoted your solution.